# Redirect based on div a href link

Tags: jquery, redirect

I'm looking for a way to redirect a page based on a div's a href link. If there is only one div on the page, then redirect to the a href link for that div.

JS

```
$(function () { 
    if ($('.div').length = 1) { alert('Just one Div'); } 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="div"><div class="title"><a href="../posters/bicycles/default.html">Bicycle</a></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What does the JavaScript signify?

Comment: window.location = $("div>a").attr("href");

Comment: And what should happen if there are more than one `<div class="div">`? And should this run when the link is clicked or on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this, returns the number of DIV elements:

```
if( $("div").length == 1 )
{
    document.location = $("div a").attr("href");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.div a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```